# Replacing the drawn geometry on 'drawend'

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

What I am trying to do is to replace or change the geometry of a feature after it has been drawn. e.g.: I draw a line and after it has been drawn I modify the geometry with `Turf.js`, to make a buffer around the drawn line and display the buffered line(polygon) instead of the line.

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vectorSource,
    type: 'LineString'
});

draw.on('drawend', function(e) {

    //Sending the LineString to a Turf function with a buffer value and getting a Polygon in return
    var bfc = bufferedFeatureCollection(100, e.feature);

    //Replacing the LineString geometry with a Polygon geometry
    e.feature.setGeometry(bfc[0].getGeometry());

    //Removes and terminates the draw action.... 
    map.removeInteraction(this);
});
```

Now from `console.log()`, I can see that the `feature.geometry` has been changed from `ol.geom.linestring` to `ol.geom.polygon`. But on the map I still see a line being displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake I made was that the buffer value was too low to be seen as a buffer hence I only saw a line(even do it was a polygon) I had to up the buffer value from `100 to 10000000`...

So in both `draw.on('drawend')` and `vectorSource.on('addfeature')` it is possible to replace the geometry that has been drawn.

**Edit:**

For the completeness of the answer. The reason I had to change the buffer from `100 to 10000000` is that I forgot to transform the geometry into `EPSG:4326`, before passing it to the Turf function. Turf only works with `EPSG:4326`.

```
var draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    source: vectorSource,
    type: 'LineString'
});

draw.on('drawend', function(e) {

    e.feature.getGeometry().transform('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');

    var bfc = bufferedFeatureCollection(radius, e.feature);
    bfc[0].getGeometry().transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');

    e.feature.setGeometry(bfc[0].getGeometry());

    //Removes and terminates the draw action....
    map.removeInteraction(this); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do these modifications after the feature is added to [`ol.source.Vector`](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html), so:

```
vectorSource.on('addfeature', function(evt){
    //Sending the LineString to a Turf function with a buffer value and getting a Polygon in return
    var bfc = bufferedFeatureCollection(100, evt.feature);

    //Replacing the LineString geometry with a Polygon geometry
    evt.feature.setGeometry(bfc[0].getGeometry());

    //Removes and terminates the draw action.... 
    map.removeInteraction(draw);
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I found out what the problem was. Your answer is correct and my code also works, so both in vectorSource.on('addfeature') and draw.on('drawend') it is possible to change the geometry. The problem was the radius of the buffer it was way too smal had to change the value from 100 to 10000000, to see the actual buffer... :S